# Show certain content to roles based on taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, users

I am trying to personalize the viewing experience for users on a site.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a view that will show content tagged with taxonomy term 'a_term' to users with the role 'a_role'.  I want to tag all of my content with these different tags so that users with 'b_role' will see content tagged with 'b_term', 'c_role' -> 'c_term', etc...

Note: these are example names for roles/terms - there will be no naming convention like this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Taxonomy Access](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access)? It allows you to set access control for roles based on taxonomy terms.

EDIT: Ignore the above dumb reply and feel free to downvote.

I think you could do this by creating a [custom contextual filter](http://treehouseagency.com/blog/neil-hastings/2010/01/19/views-handler-easy-way) in Views. Your contextual filter would look at the current user and decide which taxonomy terms ids to return.

If you are using Drupal 7 you could tag the users themselves with the same terms as a way to store which terms are associated with which users. Otherwise you might need to create a separate table to store the user to taxonomy association.

Comment: Looks great, but I don't want to restrict access to these nodes.  I want a "Things You Might Be Interested In" functionality.  I based what they're interested in on their role, which they choose when they signup.